# What does "InfoDictionary version" signify in information property list (plist file)?

Tags: ios, info.plist

What does "InfoDictionary version" signify? It is definitely different from the bundle version, but what is the role of "InfoDictionary version"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"InfoDictionary version" signifies the version information for the Info.plist format. See [Apple's doc for `CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102088) for details.

> `CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion` (`String` - iOS, macOS) identifies the current version of the property list structure. This key exists to support future versioning of the information property list file format. Xcode generates this key automatically when you build a bundle and you should not change it manually. The value for this key is currently 6.0.