# Is it safe to delete CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion?

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't want my info.plist to be cluttered. Is it safe to delete CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion? I tried removing it and run and the app still works fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, its not safe.

There's really not more to say here.

**EDIT:** See [what does the InfoDictionary version signify in the information property list (plist file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010474/what-does-the-infodictionary-version-signify-in-the-information-property-list-p) for an in-depth answer...

Comment: I'll upvote because you provide an answer and a link to more information. However, I did read up on InfoDictionary from elsewhere and know what is is or else I would not try to delete it. Better be safe than sorry I guess. I did try deleting it and it works like I said. Try it.

Comment: yes, but if some day the meaning of some of the properties change some day, you can expect to get some kind of compatibility if you include a version key. what if apple decides that every app that doesn't have a FOO33-key will have its UINavigationBars tinted pink? if you have a dict-version of 6.0 you will probably still get a non-pink navigation bar, because that's expected behaviour. if you set the dict-version to 7.0 you really are asking the OS to interpret your plist according to the new spec. and if you don't provide a dict-version, who knows what will happen?